# Where is glSwapBuffers defined?

Tags: opengl

I need to use glSwapBuffers in my code, but to my surprise, this method is not in the header GL/gl.h .
Which header file do I need to include to be able to use this method?
Not using it is not an option since I am providing an interface for other clients and this is part of the documented interface.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no function "glSwapBuffers", OpenGL doesn't define it. Swapping the front and back buffer of a double buffered window is a function provided by the underlying graphics system, i.e. Win32 GDI, or X11 GLX. The function's you're looking for are `wglSwapBuffers` and/or `glXSwapBuffers`. On MacOS X NSOpenGLViews are automatically swapped.

However most likely you're using some framework, like GLUT, GLFW or Qt, which provide a portable wrapper around those functions. Read the framework's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I know not to look for glSwapBuffers .

Answer (score -2):

Use glSwapAPPLE() or aglSwapBuffer()